# My GitHub action is just hanging in the starting status with no logs, what is happening?

Tags: git, github-actions

I have tried rebuilding several times (pushing new changes to the PR), but it just keeps hanging like this:

[image]

There is no indication that the build has even *started*, so there are no logs to inspect. It just hangs like this for the past while.

What is the reason for this? What is happening? I would assume potentially one of my scripts (which happens after installing github actions@v2 and the Node.js actions) could be hanging, but if that were the case I would at least think I would see previous logs from Node.js installing and such.

Why is it hanging? This is for a private repo so can't share code. My config is this:

```
name: build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  run:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - name: Configure Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Lint Markdown
        run: make lint
```

Answer (score 0):

To save others the headache, it was because I had this in my config file, *while also requiring that this be run before merging the PR.*

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

So it never ran, because it was on a branch, and just hangs.